# Big Oh Notation for summation

Tags: analysis, functions, asymptotics

The Big Oh Notation is important to classify the asymptotic behavior of functions, but I don't how to work with these on summations

We have two functions $\ f,g$

$$f(n)=\sum^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}_{i=1} 3^i$$ 
$$g(n)=n^2$$

Now I have to determine which Big Oh Rule applies here; in other words we want to know if function $f$ is growing faster than $g$ etc or function $g$ is growing faster than $f$ etc.

(1) $f(n)=\mathcal{O}(g(n))$

(2) $f(n)=\mathcal{o}(g(n))$

(3) $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$

(4) $f(n)=\omega(g(n))$

(5) $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$

I generally know how to use these rules but summations aren't typical functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the sum to something you're more familiar with. In the above, the sum is a geometric sum, which has the value
$$
\sum_{i=0}^N a^i = \frac{a^{N+1}-1}{a-1}. 
$$
With $N = \log_2 n$ and $a=3$ (don't worry about floors since they don't have that much influence in asymptotic behavior), your $f$ looks something like
$$
\frac{3^{\log_2 n}}2 = \frac{n^{\log_2 3}}2. 
$$

Since $\log_2 3\approx1.58496$, you can expect your $f$ to be faster than $n^2$.

Comment: Thank you, I am familiar with geometric sum, we can conclude that $f(n)=n^2$ grows faster than $\frac{n^{\log_2 3}}2$

Comment: why the last equality?

Comment: You have that $\log_2(3^{\log_2 n}) = \log_2 n\log_2 3 = \log_2(n^{\log_2 3})$. Now do you see it?

Comment: nice... first time I see this simple identity.

Comment: I also first learned of it in this context :)